# Merging contents of multiple files in windows platform

Tags: python, merge, window

Is there any option in python to merge contents of multiple files in a particular directory and to create a new file in the same directory with the merged contents?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `glob` to give you a list of files, e.g. `*.txt` or `*.*` and then read/write them in a loop as follows:

```
import glob

output = 'merged.txt'

with open(output, 'w') as f_merged:
    for filename in glob.glob('*.*'):
        if filename != output:
            with open(filename) as f_input:
                f_merged.writelines(f_input)
```